# Calculate Euclidean distance on numpy row-row cross product?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays with `n` number of coordinates (two items per row).

```py
coords_a = np.random.random((20, 2))
coords_b = np.random.random((20, 2))
```

Now, for each combination of rows, I want to compute a function and save the return value as item in a matrix. The resulting array should therefore have shape `(20, 20)` and can be "lazily" computed as shown below. As exemplary function, the Euclidean distance is used.

```py
def euclidean_dist(x1: float, y1: float, x2: float, y2: float) -> float:
    """Return the euclidean distance between two the points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2)."""
    return np.sqrt(np.square(x1 - x2) + np.square(y1 - y2))

matrix = []
for a in coords_a:
    row = []
    for b in coords_b:
        row.append(euclidean_dist(*a, *b))
    matrix.append(row)
    
matrix = np.array(matrix)
```

As you can imagine, this nested for loop is very time consuming taking over 25 seconds with just 2000 coordinate pairs. Is there a recommended way of vectoring this sort of cross product?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need the calculations to be lazy? Can you please elaborate on your actual problem? Would you be able to do per column calculations? and how large your arrays are?

Comment: "Lazy" was referring to my example below as it's not vectorised. My problem is that this computation has to be performed on a few thousand sets each containing between 2000 and 5000 coordinates.

Comment: a 5000x5000(X4floats) calculation should be easy to compute vectorized with pretty much any system. So what is your function exactly that you wish to vectorize? It depends on the function. For example, for Euclidean distance, there are built-in functions.

Comment: Sorry for not understanding. I will use the Euclidean distance (mathematical distance between two coordinates) – applied to all combinations of rows.

Comment: I think a vectorized implementation depends upon the function you need to apply.

Comment: For functions that are available as ufuncs in numpy, I bet taking the outer product across the ufunc would be much, much faster.  But any arbitrary function will not necessarily be available that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific example you can do:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
cdist(coords_b,coords_a)
```

In general, vectorizing depends on your function.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add my 2 cents since not every function is already implemented in numpy or scipy. In general you can use [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to achieve vectorized solution.
For the specific case of euclidean distance here how you do it:

```py
import numpy as np

# Define the arrays of coordinates
coords_a = np.random.random((20, 2))
coords_b = np.random.random((20, 2))

# Expand their dimensions
a = coords_a[:, None]
b = coords_b[None, None]

# Use broadcasting to compute pairwise difference
d = a-b

# Apply formula for euclidean distance
r = np.sqrt(np.sum(d**2, axis=-1))
```

In terms of time performance for this specific case `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` is way faster, yet not every function is available:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

a = np.random.random((10_000, 2))
b = np.random.random((10_000, 2))

euc_broadcast = lambda a,b: np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(a[:, None]-b[None, :]), axis=-1))

%timeit euc_broadcast(a, b)
3.39 s ± 149 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit cdist(a, b)
603 ms ± 13.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: This is a super helpful answer. I was looking for exactly this, but took a while to find!